# Configure JBOSS EAP Server and Load Balancer

Tags: webserver, load-balancing, high-availability, jboss-eap-6, disaster-recovery

We need to setup JBOSS Server , Load Balancer for our Java/J2EE application in production server for approx 5000 users.
Can someone please elaborate on infrastructure required , like suitable Hardware ?
What kind on Web Server , then Application server like JBOSS EAP , How to setup load balancer , enable audit logs. Configure clustering, fail over and load balancing. Configure Web Connectors and web properties in JBoss applications.
High availability and disaster recovery. These topics are very important.
 I am actually a developer , have never configured deployment environment in production as an Administrator. I tried to search similar post , but got no results.  Please guide the architecture as guideline. I will explore it further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked about a huge range of topics here. You can find guides on how to set up and configure most of them in the JBoss EAP documentation, which is available here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/